# React-Router always appending Other site's URl to the Base url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router for the first time and i am stuck at this stage for about a day where react-router just appends URL (which refers to a different site like 'google.com') to my base url and gives query like 'http://localhost:3000/google.com' can someone explain this to me why this is happening?

```
<SlideCard onClick={() => moveSlide(offsetFromMiddle)}>
        <a href={'www.github.com'} target={''} rel={'noreferrer'} className={'a_no_style'}>
            {content}
        </a>
</SlideCard>
```

this is the code i am stuck in

Comment: I can't even see any router related code in here? Is there more code mate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because when u give  a href in your a tag like this, that goes to append the url that you gave to current url, if you want to change your all directory, you can add https:// in the beginnig. If you don't that will add it to your current url. That's what I get actually.

Comment: Preceeding the url with 'https://' fixed this issue for me.